# HTML5 - Downloading video to local device and then playing it later

Tags: html, video, download

Much like in some of the existing applications available on the App store (which are probably Native apps), I have been tasked with a requirement to download video content to a mobile / tablet application, and be able to play the same when offline. The requirement is on HTML5. While I have researched various articles which guide in terms of using the video tag, it seems that the browser streams video or else downloads it on-demand. I havent found an answer to my particular problem where the video download is a separate activity from playing the same. Also looked at the FileSystem API but it seems that the same is not yet supported on the latest iOS or Android browser. Any advice / pointers would be great. The video files would be typically > 20 Mbs each. Thanks!

Comment: Create separate link for video download as file. Because of this lack of support at the file system API, the HTML 5 compatible browsers cannot offer you at the moment "Save As" functionality if the file is not in the open source format, like ogg.

Answer (score 0):

## Not possible

That kind of functionality does not exist.  My gut says it may never exist with iOS devices.  You're going to need to find another approach.